# How to delete penultimate 0 in numeric column?

Tags: r, regex

In numeric column old_code of dataframe df1 my integers have this structure:

```
    head(df1$old_code)
    [1] 12101 18201 13202 11301 13302 10401
```

In the column new_code I would like the same exact integers, minus the second to last 0 (i.e. 12101 I would like to see as 1011, 18201 as 1021). I am positive this is solved using regex but I can't crack the code.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your example doesn't really look like "minus the second to last 0". Replacing 12101 by 1011 seems like replacing 2 (two steps before last 0) by 0 and dropping the last 0. Same with 18201 and 1021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `gsub`:

```
gsub("(.*)0(.)$", "\\1\\2", df$old_code)
# [1] "1211" "1821" "1322" "1131" "1332" "1041"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting it into a string:

```
df$old_code=as.character(df$old_code) 
a= substr(df$old_code, 1, 1) 
b=substr(df$old_code, 3,nchar(df$old_code)) 
df$old_code=paste0(a,b) 
df$old_code=as.integer(df$old_code)
```